# Working with Mysql and servlets in Java

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, servlets

I'm looking forward to reduce the **initialization** time of MySQL when working on servlets. It looks like this is a hard thing to do, so I need a better solution.

Is there any preloaded way to solve this? 
Something like a pool or whatever? (I don't know what I'm talking about).

**SCENARIO**
User sets login parameters.
Press Login button.
MySQL initializes (5 secs!!).
Still loads...
User thinks service is not working.
User closes tabs.

Comment: I was trying to suggest solutions, as I'm short on ideas this time. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Indeed this is exactly what I am looking! Thank you very much, again.

Comment: Your servlet container (Tomcat, Glassfish, whatever) ought to have some kind of DB connection pool you can use. You _definitely_ don't want to be doing your own jdbc / jndi _Naming.lookup()_ and bringing connections up and down all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce connection time in a servlet, usually a database conenction pool is used.  This will take care of initializing connections and allocating them for you.

see https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

for an example jar